# How to Handle Infinity in calculations?

Tags: functions

In my numerical calculations I have a list of Eigenvalues with some of them equal to zero. So, when I calculate the `log` to the base `2` I get `infinity` those eigenvalues due to `Log[2,0]` output.

**Question**: How can I avoid `Log[2,0]` in my lengthy code, i.e. to get `0` instead of `-Infinity`?

Thanks and regards

Comment: What do you want it to be equal to instead? `0`?

Comment: @march yes i want it equal to zero instead of infinity

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: @Rahul, this would also be the first time I've seen anyone wanting to zero out an infinite logarithm, but there certainly is precedent for zeroing out an infinity: consider the computation of the pseudoinverse from the SVD. Now, whether this zeroing out is appropriate here… is the OP's responsibility.

Comment: @Usman, do you think you will ever start to accept the answers to your questions according to the site charter? It helps other users and clean the site queue...

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume you want to avoid indeterminate values by replacing them with 0

```
ClearAll@LogTwo
SetAttributes[LogTwo, {Listable, NumericFunction}]

LogTwo[0 | 0.] := 0
LogTwo[x_?NumericQ] := Log2[x]

list = {1, 0, 2.};

Log[2, list]
```

> {0, -Infinity, 1.}

```
LogTwo[list]
```

> {0, 0, 1.}

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to directly set the unwanted infinities to zero:

```
list = {1, 0, 2.};
Log[list] /. {Infinity -> 0, -Infinity -> 0}

{0, 0, 0.693147}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [constrain on pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html) and use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`):

```
list = {1, 1., 0, 0., 2, 2.}

list /. (x_ /; x > 0) -> Log2[x]
```

or

```
list /. x_?Positive -> Log[2, x]
```

Result:

> `{0, 0., 0, 0., 1, 1.}`